# Styling menu size with FireMonkey

Tags: menu, size, firemonkey, tmenuitem

I am trying to increase the size of a the drop-down items in a TMenuBar menu using FireMonkey on Windows platform (because when using a touch-screen it is difficult to press the right menu item).
I thought I should be able to do this by changing the X and Y scaling of menuitemstyle in my stylebook, but when I do, it changes only the size of the contents of the menu, and not the structure containing the contents, as shown here.[image]
I have tried playing with all the size options I can find, but haven't found a way to change the size of the elements that drop down. Does anybody have any suggestions to fix this problem, please?

Comment: You can change the fixedheight of the menubaritemstyle (by code or modifying style) 
But, it seems that there is still a problem because the items will not all be visible, the list does not take into account the defined height :(

Comment: Thank you. That certainly helps. (I thought I had already tried it, but must have done something wrong.) If I also change the FixedWidth and FixedHeight properties of the menuviewstyle element I think I can get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the fixedheight of the menubaritemstyle (by code or modifying style) is not the better solution because submenu don't behave correctly.
I found a better way, not involving style, even if at this moment I don't see how to take care of MenuBar Height .

If you have the sources, copy the FMX.Menu.pas into the app directory.
Change file attribute, removing readonly.
Go to line 1636 D11  *line 1650 for D12
You can see that **a constant** 23 is used for the height.

Change it to the value you want.

P.S. I tried FContent.Height, but this gave me a 50 value, that why I suggest a copy of the original source.

Add this new unit to the project and submenu should be OK